# Obscure Antlr Error when Parsing Data Type

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I am trying to parse a variable type for a toy language meant to teach Antlr fundamentals. I wish to parse at the rule `var` using the below code.

```
    // Parser
    var : TYPE ID;
    // Lexer
    TYPE: SIGNED     PTR? DIMENSIONS?
        | UNSIGNED   PTR? DIMENSIONS?
        | UNSIGNABLE PTR? DIMENSIONS?;
    fragment DIMENSIONS : '[' ((NAT | ':') ',')* (NAT | ':')? ']';
    fragment SIGNED     : 'I16'   | 'I32'   | 'I64'   | 'F32'   | 'CHAR';
    fragment UNSIGNED   : 'U_I16' | 'U_I32' | 'U_I64' | 'U_F32' | 'U_CHAR';
    fragment UNSIGNABLE : 'VOID'  | 'STR'   | 'BOOL'  | 'CPLX';
    PTR : 'PTR';
    NAT : [0-9]+;
    ID  : [A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*;
```

However, when I test my program with the example declaration `I32 HELLO_9`, I receive the following error.

> line 1:0 missing TYPE at 'I32'

`PTR` and `DIMENSIONS` should be marked as optional, so I am unsure as to why my lexer will not identify the `I32` token for the `SIGNED` fragment. As a secondary question, I wonder how it is ever possible for professional programmers to create sophisticated projects with Antlr. I have experimented with Haskell parsing libraries in the past and it appears (from my subjective view) that Antlr is more prone to producing obscure errors. My perception is probably just a consequence of my inexperience, and I would be thankful to hear the opinions of a more suave programmer.

Comment: Please paste your entire grammar. (Afaik, Antlr4 will reject that because it is missing a `grammar` statement; moreover, there is no pattern to skip whitespace, so the space character should trigger an error.) Filling in those details plausibly, I couldn't reproduce your problem. If I had to hazard a guess, I'd go for "you are using Windows and your source file actually starts with a UTF-8 BOM." But, of course, that could be completely out to lunch. The more details you can provide, the easier it is to provide help.

Comment: (Indeed, inserting a UTF-8 BOM into the input produces something very close to the error you report, although the wording is different, probably because I'm using the Antlr4 TestRig. It would also be useful to know the exact commands you used to run the parser.)

Answer (score 0):

Given your grammar, I can't reproduce this. If I add `SPACE : [ \t\r\n] -> skip;` to it, the following code:

```java
TLexer lexer = new TLexer(CharStreams.fromString("I32 HELLO_9"));
TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
ParseTree root = parser.var();
System.out.println(root.toStringTree(parser));
```

produces no warnings/errors and prints:

```
(var I32 HELLO_9)
```

representing the parse tree:

[image]

The real problem is something @rici mentioned, or it is hidden by the fact that you've minimized your real grammar and this minimized form does not produce the error your real grammar does.